# How do I get the print statement to tell me the date of the authors' death?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to make it say 'author' died in 'date', but it won't work.

```
authors = {
   "Charles Dickens": "1870",
   "William Thackeray": "1863",
   "Anthony Trollope": "1882",
   "Gerard Manley Hopkins": "1889"
   }
for author, date in authors.items():
   print( "%s" % authors + " died in "  + date)
```

Comment: this is the desired format.

Comment: Charles Dickens, 1870
William Thackeray, 1863
Anthony Trollope, 1882
Gerard Manley Hopkins, 1889

Comment: this is what keeps showing up

Comment: {'Charles Dickens': '1870', 'William Thackeray': '1863', 'Anthony Trollope': '1882', 'Gerard Manley Hopkins': '1889'} died in 1870
{'Charles Dickens': '1870', 'William Thackeray': '1863', 'Anthony Trollope': '1882', 'Gerard Manley Hopkins': '1889'} died in 1863
{'Charles Dickens': '1870', 'William Thackeray': '1863', 'Anthony Trollope': '1882', 'Gerard Manley Hopkins': '1889'} died in 1882
{'Charles Dickens': '1870', 'William Thackeray': '1863', 'Anthony Trollope': '1882', 'Gerard Manley Hopkins': '1889'} died in 1889

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the name of the variable inside the print from **authors** (your full dict) to **author**, representing each instance of the collection:

```
authors = {
   "Charles Dickens": "1870",
   "William Thackeray": "1863",
   "Anthony Trollope": "1882",
   "Gerard Manley Hopkins": "1889"
   }
for author, date in authors.items():
    print( "%s" % author + " died in "  + date)
```

This produces the following output:

```
Charles Dickens died in 1870
William Thackeray died in 1863
Anthony Trollope died in 1882
Gerard Manley Hopkins died in 1889
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple and easy to understand solution

```
for author, date in authors.items():
   print( author + " died in "  + date)
```

output

```
Charles Dickens died in 1870
William Thackeray died in 1863
Anthony Trollope died in 1882
Gerard Manley Hopkins died in 1889
```

Comment: This is the same answer as the top answer. What is different?

Comment: i have used the string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You can use format for that

```
authors = {
   "Charles Dickens": "1870",
   "William Thackeray": "1863",
   "Anthony Trollope": "1882",
   "Gerard Manley Hopkins": "1889"
   }
for author, date in authors.items():
     print('{}, in {}'.format(author, date)))
```

Or f-string Python 3.6 and above

```
for author, date in authors.items():
   print('{author}, in {date}'))
```

Output

```
Charles Dickens, in 1870
William Thackeray, in 1863
Anthony Trollope, in 1882
Gerard Manley Hopkins, in 1889
```

Comment: Note that f-strings are python 3.6 and above only.

Comment: Tnx for that note

Answer (score 0):

```
for author, date in authors.items():
   print( "%s" % author + " died in "  + date)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's useful to put some additional information, explaining what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `authors` in `print` statement to `author`,
you can use multiple styles of print for your purpose choose one of them wisely,

```
authors = {
   "Charles Dickens": "1870",
   "William Thackeray": "1863",
   "Anthony Trollope": "1882",
   "Gerard Manley Hopkins": "1889"
   }
for author, date in authors.items():
   #your statement
   print( "%s" % author + " died in "  + date)

   #using f before the string for python 3.6 and above
   print(f"{author} died in {date}")


   #using format() method of string
   print("{0} died in {1}".format(author,date))

   #using string concatenation
   print(author + " died in "+date)
```

Every statement prints same output but some techniques are more useful than others such as using `f` or `format()` gives you more flexibility.

Hope this helps you!